# Can anyone help me to write test case for the following action?

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, react-redux

```
export const fetchP2pPriceConstraints = () => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const response = await api.fetchP2pConstraints();
    const apiResponse = await response.data;
    if (response.status === 200 && apiResponse.code === 200) {
      dispatch({
        type: PRICE_CONSTRAINTS,
        payload: {
          priceConstraints: apiResponse.result,
        },
      });
      return Promise.resolve(apiResponse);
    }
    return Promise.reject(response);
  };
};
```

This is the redux action that I need to cover in my test case I tried different approaches but nothing worked so well.

Answer (score -1):

```
it('test p2p price constraints action', () => {
    store.dispatch(fetchP2pPriceConstraints()).then(() => {
      let expectedActions = [
        {
          type: PRICE_CONSTRAINTS,
          payload: {
            priceConstraints: {},
          },
        },
      ];

      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
```

I tried this, it is working but not covering all the lines.